# OpenApi generator - change host by default

Tags: java, yaml, pom.xml, openapi, openapi-generator

I need to change the **host** value every time when generating the Java classes.

Here is my documentation file.

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.14"
  title: Some title
host: api.default.host
basePath: /base/path/
schemes:
  - https

// ....
```

I tried something like this, but unfortunately, it doesn't work

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testId</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                         
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/test.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.test.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.test.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.test.invoker</invokerPackage>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <globalFeatures>
                                    <host>targetHost</host>
                                </globalFeatures>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                            </configOptions>
                            <library>jersey2</library>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I use version 3.3.4 of generator and can't change due to company's policy.

Comment: Just after quickly looking through the documents for 3.3.4, it doesn't appear that there is anyway to adjust the host name on the fly. I'd suggest modifying the generated `openapi.json` with a maven plugin prior to deployment.

Answer (score 0):

@tbtach comment about using a Maven plugin to modify the file helped me find a solution using maven-replacer-plugin, which allows you to modify "tokens" from any file in your project: https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin/.

See a working example here in the 1st part of the question: [maven-replacer-plugin and multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157779/maven-replacer-plugin-and-multiple-files)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).